# Multiple pojo clasess in dispatcher-servlet

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two pojo clasess

Loan.java
Customer.java

But i cannot include those two pojo clasess in the dispatcher-servlet.xml
this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="system"/>
        <property name="password" value="newuser123#"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.pojo.Customer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myLoanDAO" class="com.dao.LoanDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/viewloan.htm" class="com.Controller.LoanController" p:formView="Customer" p:successView="loan_view" p:orderDAO-ref="myLoanDAO"  >
    </bean>

    <bean name="/profile.htm" class="com.Controller.CustomerController" p:formView="profile_view" p:orderDAO-ref="myLoanDAO"  >
    </bean>
</beans>
```

How to also include the Customer Entity class alongwith the Loan Entity class.
i am getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.pojo.Customer
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:175)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:479)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:716)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:427)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:341)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:214)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:556)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:402)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:249)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:267)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:245)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:260)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


**root cause** 

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.pojo.Customer
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:626)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:452)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:268)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:175)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:479)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:716)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:427)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:341)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:214)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:556)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:402)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:249)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:267)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:245)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:260)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add `Loan` as annotated class in configuration

```
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.pojo.Customer</value>
            <value>com.pojo.Loan</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Next, `No identifier specified for entity: com.pojo.Customer` means you haven't specified which field is the ID for `Customer` entity. You need something like this in it

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

This goes for all your entity classes.

Comment: Is the exception the same, or is there a different message? Post the code of `Customer` into the question.